# How do you add a table in OneNote 16.24 for iPhone?

Tags: ios, ms-office

On both versions of the desktop app I'm able to add a table, but in the mobile version 16.24 on iOS 12.2 I'm unable to add a table.

Most wiki's have a syntax for this, I guess OneNote is a note taking app, and so that makes it different.

Comment: I don’t see the option/ menu to do so.

Comment: I deleted the comment because it was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Numbers spreadsheet app, you can copy and paste the cells into OneNote.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Microsoft has not added the ability to create tables on the iPhone.

Tables can be created in iOS using an iPad only (which is why I posted my comment; since deleted).  This feature has been missing since OneNote was introduced.